# Writing "Res" as "Residue" (Mathematical Notation on Complex Analysis)

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, scientific-notation

I can't found `Res` command on Detexify. So, how to write `Res` on LaTeX?
If I use `\text{Res}` it becomes italic when I'm using `\begin{theorem}` environment. And I want it to be as usual normal text (straight form).

I've tried to search on this site and can't found about this and am now asking for help.

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator\Res{Res}` (requires `\usepackage{amsmath}` which you probably already have)

Comment: @HenriMenke Thank you